# MarkLogic localhost connection not accepted by remote device or resource

Tags: connection, localhost, marklogic

Once the MarkLogic service started, I tried to connect to localhost:8001.
I was prompted to request for student/developer/express license. I requested developer license and obtained it. MarkLogic tried to reconfigure with default configuration and failed with below error:

> ERROR
>
> The remote device or resource won't accept the connection The device or resource localhost:8001 is not set up to accept connections
> on port "8001". Contact your network administrator The computer or
> device you are trying to reach is available, but it doesn’t support
> what you’re trying to do. This might be a configuration issue or a
> limitation of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to refresh after waiting a minute?

It is not unlikely MarkLogic had to restart for some reason. Normally it warns about this, and shows a automatically reloading page, but sometimes it initiates the restart quicker than it can show the page, and the browser ends up showing a failed to connect message like above. That isn't harmfull, just wait till `MarkLogic` is up again, which usually takes no more than one or two minute.

If it persists, check whether the `MarkLogic` service is up and running. If it is down, try to restart it manually. If even that fails, check `ErrorLog.txt`, and if even that doesn't help, just contact support at `marklogic.com`.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

That error message looks like a generic one from the browser. If refreshing the page doesn't work, check the ErrorLog.txt file to see what the problem might be: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/logfiles#id_22670

If the log doesn't contain an obvious problem, the next step is to contact support.